# Cannot find type 'ChartViewDelegate' in scope, multiple new compile errors

Tags: ios-charts

I have just opened up my project to make some minor fixes.  It was fully working two weeks ago and was the basis for my recent release.  Without making any changes, I have a large number of compile errors related to my use of ios Charts.  It looks like I have lost all the pod-files associated with ios-charts.  Is this an issue with Xcode (I'm on 14.3) and will I have to reinstall ios-Charts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did something rather dumb and opened the myproject.xcodeproject file rather than the myproject.xcworkspace file.  The pods are olaced only in the xcworkspace.  Somehow my recent project list pointed to the wrong file and this gave me the issue.